# restoring list from unified_diff output

Tags: python

I need to generate the diff between two arrays of strings:

```
a=['1','2']
b=['1','2','3']
```

To achieve this I'm using the difflib library in Python (2.6):

```
c=difflib.unified_diff(a,b)
```

and I save the content of

```
d=list(c)
```

which is something like:

```
['---  \n', '+++  \n', '@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@\n', ' 1', ' 2', '+3']
```

How can I build the second array from the first using the output of the unified_diff function?

The behavior that I'm looking for is something like:

```
>>> merge(a,d)
>>> ['1','2','3']
```

P.S. the array can have duplicate entries and the order in which each entry appears is important for my application. Moreover, from one iteration to another there could be changes both in the middle/begin of the array, as well as new entries added at the end.

Comment: `unified_diff` is for comparing strings? Why are you using is to compare python objects?

Comment: i need to periodically transfer over a wireless link a long list of numbers. every iteration only a few entries in the list change. I've realized that the output of unified_diff is a LOT shorter than the size of the updated list.

Comment: Calculate the difference, serialise (`pickle`)  the output, send it over the network link and un-serialise it.

Comment: still i do not understand how I can merge the un-serialized differences at the destination. basically i'm looking for the equivalent of the patch command.

Comment: if the object you want to compare, diff and merge is a `list`, you just `.append()` to the list on the receiving side.

Comment: This would work only if changes are only new entries at the end of the list. In my case the list can have changes at any point, that is why the unified_diff looked so good to me, basically I can have a ten-fold reduction in the number of bytes sent over the link. However I do not know how to re-build everything at the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that my sample is a good style, but you can use something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

a=['1','2']
b=['1','2','3']

a.extend(b)

[k for k,v in Counter(a).items() if v == 1]
```

OR if your lists could have only unique items:

```
list(set(a) ^ set(b))
```

OR:

```
missed_in_a = [x for x in a if x not in b]
missed_in_b = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

OR:

```
a=['1','2']
b=['1','2','3']

c = [x for x in a]
c.extend(b)

diff = [x for x in c if a.count(x)+b.count(x) == 1]
```

The last one(hope i understand you correctly(sorry if not so) now):

```
a = ['1','2','3','4']
b = ['2','2','3','6','5']

from difflib import unified_diff

def merge(a,b):
    output = []
    for line in list(unified_diff(a,b))[3:]:
        if '+' in line:
            output.append(line.strip('+'))
        elif not '-' in line:
            output.append(line.strip())
    return output

print merge(a,b)
```

Comment: I cannot use python 3, the software is running on an embedded platform running OpenWRT.

Comment: Counter was added in 2.7, on my platform I can use only 2.6.

Comment: Then why to not use solution with set or the last one? Sorry if i miss something

Comment: because there could be duplicated entries and the order is important to me

Comment: Not sure that i correctly understand you - you want to merge lists using their position? If so what is the rule - whose values should be included if both have values and these values are not equal? Could you please add more details into the your question so we will have ability to answer you.

Comment: I want to use the output of the unified_diff function to rebuild the original list. in this way I can send the entire list first and then only the changes.